# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near ','.'

Tags: c#, sql

I have created this code to add new records to the database however, every time I rum the code I get this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near ','.'

And I have no idea how to fix this error, I have looked online and tried different ways to fix it and none of them helped or fixed the problem.

The code is found below:

```
SqlCommand sdk = new SqlCommand("SELECT ([Id],[Title],[JobInfo],[DateSet],[DateDue],[WhoFor]) FROM Information_Schema.Columns FROM JobInformation", ConnectToDatabase);

ConnectToDatabase.Open();
SqlDataReader reader;
reader = sdk.ExecuteReader();
ConnectToDatabase.Close();
```

I believe it to be the first line of code, but I have no clue where the error could be within it.

Comment: You have _two_ `FROM` clauses, is that legal SQL?

Comment: You don't need brackets for the `select`, and you have two `from` - what are you trying to do here?

Comment: Think your SQL query is not correct.

Comment: The `SELECT` is from `Information_Schema.Columns` or from `JobInformation`?

Comment: as a side note, you also aren't actually reading the data before you close the connection

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL server built into Visual studio 2017

Comment: I am trying to, when the user enters information into the program and then presses the Submit button the information is transferred to the database

Comment: If you are trying to achieve that _information is transferred to the database_...a select won't help you i think

Comment: but... a `select` query doesn't transfer information *to* the database - that queries information *from* the database?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect you mean something like:

```
ConnectToDatabase.Open();
using(var sdk = new SqlCommand(
    "SELECT [Id],[Title],[JobInfo],[DateSet],[DateDue],[WhoFor] FROM JobInformation",
    ConnectToDatabase))
using(var reader = sdk.ExecuteReader())
{
    while(reader.Read()) { /* process row */
}
ConnectToDatabase.Close();
```

However, you may find it easier to use a tool like [dapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper):

```
var jobs = ConnectToDatabase.Query<JobInfo>(
      "SELECT [Id],[Title],[JobInfo],[DateSet],[DateDue],[WhoFor] FROM JobInformation"
     ).AsList();
```

(which does everything including the open/close, *and* populates the columns into your own `JobInfo` type that you need to create)

---

However, you say:

> I have created this code to add new records to the database

in which case you'll need to use `insert`, not `select` - and the `ExecuteNonQuery` method of `SqlCommand` (or the `Execute` method of "dapper").

For an insert:

```
using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(@"
    insert JobInformation(Title, JobInfo, DateSet, DateDue, WhoFor)
    values (@title, @jobInfo, @dateSet, @dateDue, @whoFor)", ConnectToDatabase))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", title);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jobInfo", jobInfo);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateSet", dateSet);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateDue", dateDue);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@whoFor", whoFor);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

}

or with dapper:

```
ConnectToDatabase.Execute(@"
    insert JobInformation(Title, JobInfo, DateSet, DateDue, WhoFor)
    values (@title, @jobInfo, @dateSet, @dateDue, @whoFor)",
    new { title, jobInfo, dateSet, dateDue, whoFor});
```

Comment: @jamieshepherd where? in the question?

Comment: SqlCommand sdk = new SqlCommand("SELECT ([Id],[Title],[JobInfo],[DateSet],[DateDue],[WhoFor]) FROM Information_Schema.Columns FROM JobInformation", ConnectToDatabase);

Comment: SqlCommand sdk = new SqlCommand("INSERT ([Id],[Title],[JobInfo],[DateSet],[DateDue],[WhoFor]) FROM Information_Schema.Columns FROM JobInformation", ConnectToDatabase);

Comment: I am also trying your solution

Comment: I think you need to read **a lot more** about sql language syntax before trying to code anything @jamieshepherd ...

Comment: @jamieshepherd why do you keep touching `Information_Schema.Columns`? what did that table ever do to you? I will edit my answer to show the syntax for an insert

Comment: I has worked and I am not receive the anymore, however, I cannot input the data into the database

Comment: ConnectToDatabase.Open();
            using (var sdk = new SqlCommand(
                "INSERT INTO [Id],[Title],[JobInfo],[DateSet],[DateDue],[WhoFor] WHERE JobInformation",
                ConnectToDatabase))
            using (var reader = sdk.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    while (reader.Read()) ;
                }

Comment: Again I need to insert into the database however it is giving me another error: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near ','.'

Comment: @E.Del that suggested edit might be OK as a comment, but not really as an edit; that isn't what I said, and doesn't improve my answer any...

Comment: .@jamieshepherd again, the code in your  comments here is *not even remotely* like valid TSQL, and the `ExecuteReader` method is incorrect here. Please look at the code in the edited answer.